# coding first php cart - advice needed

Tags: php, cart

I'm a php noob attempting my first shopping cart. I intend to use paypal checkout when the cart is ready. I'm having fun playing with this but need assistance.

Here is what I got so far: futurekode.com/uikits/store.php

I'm using form post to send the quantities to the cart.php page.

My question is how do I populate the table on the cart.php page with all the info like product name and price? Do I need to setup a database or could I use hidden inputs?

Any advice and sample code is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database will be the preference, for persistence, but you can use a [session](http://www.php.net/sessions) which will be much better than hidden inputs.

Comment: how would I use session for this.. can you give example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a self-admitted PHP 'noob', would it not be better for you to use a free shopping cart system such as [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com) or [Cube Cart](http://www.cubecart.com)?

These pre-existing shopping carts will be able to offer you a much quicker solution as you won't need to code them, will likely have better security in place, and even integration with PayPal.

Comment: It probably would be easier/quicker, but this cart is going to be a very simple operation so I want to do it myself for the challenge and the experience.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you will be appreciating some code let me first give you the link for PHP Paypal SDK with which you can use following options for your checkout [**PAYPAL PHP SDK**](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)

```
 DoDirectPayment - Sale
 DoDirectPayment - Authorization
 ExpressCheckout - Sale
 ExpressCheckout - Authorization
 ExpressCheckout - Order
 DoDirectPayment - 3DSecure - Sale
```

Just download sdk for php from here reflect your paypal test account changes and enjoy the code